# NullPointer Exception in a java client?

Tags: java, eclipse, sockets, exception, nullpointerexception

I am coding a simple client, but I always get a `NullPointerException` at:

```
            while ((input = in.readLine()) != null) {
```

Here is my code:

```
public class ClientTest {

public static String server = "127.0.0.1";
public static int sport = 11111;
public static int cport = 11111;
private static String clientname="";
public static ExecutorService pool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
public static BufferedReader in = null;
public static PrintWriter out = null;
public static Socket socket = null;

public ClientTest(){
    this.clientname="";
}


public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        socket = new Socket(server, sport);
        out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
    } catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println("could not create connection:\n" + e);
        try {
            if(socket != null) socket.close();
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    pool.execute(new Communicator());

}

public static class Communicator implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        String input = "";
        try {
            while ((input = in.readLine()) != null) {//here  i get the NPException
                StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(input);
                tokenizer.nextToken();

                if(input.startsWith("!open")) {
                    if(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) System.out.print(tokenizer.nextToken() + "> ");
                    else System.out.print("> ");
                } 
                else if(input.startsWith("!exit")) {
                    System.out.print("Hallo hallo");
                } 
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("An error as occurred while reading from server - \n" + e);
        }
    }

}


}
```

Why do I get the `NullPointerException`? I am still initializing the String input.

Comment: you should add where you are getting null pointer exception or total error message

Comment: check what the value of in is ... chances are it is what's giving you the nullpointer exception.

Comment: Do you get a message says ' could not create connection: ...'  If yes,  socket itself not connected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> My question is, why do I get the NP Exception, I am still initializing the String input!

You would get a `NullPointerException` there if `in` is null... which it certainly could be. After all, if anything in the first part of `main` throws an exception, you catch it, print it out... and then keep going! So if `socket.getOutputStream()` throws an exception, both `in` and `out` will be null.

Moral: catching an exception and just continuing as if nothing had happened is *very rarely* a good idea.

Comment: @maximus: You only initialize it if an exception isn't thrown by earlier statements...

Answer (score 0):

I think something in the try block is failing and `in` is not being initialized, then after the exception you are running `Comunicator` and `in` is still null.